# ASP.NET SessionID type

Tags: asp.net, sessionid

I was wondering if anyone knew what was the format of a ASP.NET SessionID?
It's not a GUID or base64, what is its type? Also does it vary from version to version of the .NET framework?

thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Edited.  Revised from my original dumb answer.**

The documentation just says it's randomly asigned by ASP.NET.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.sessionid.aspx

[Another page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionidmanager.aspx) gives a bit more detail.

> The ASP.NET session identifier is a
>   randomly generated number encoded into
>   a 24-character string consisting of
>   lowercase characters from a to z and
>   numbers from 0 to 5.

Comment: Well I was hoping from a security point-of-view is SHA256 or above. The advantages of using sha256 or above is crashing doesn’t work effectively.  Also I looking at saving the session id to a logging database and question was posed could I use a unique Identifier. This got me thinking what was the sessionID type.  All Microsoft Documentation told me nothing.
 
Thanks for your information.